# How do I output PHP array function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, printing, echo

I'm having problems trying to "print" a PHP function to convert an IP address range to CIDR format, here is the function posted by IP2Location.com :

https://www.ip2location.com/tutorials/how-to-convert-ip-address-range-into-cidr

```
function iprange2cidr($ipStart, $ipEnd){
    if (is_string($ipStart) || is_string($ipEnd)){
        $start = ip2long($ipStart);
        $end = ip2long($ipEnd);
    }
    else{
        $start = $ipStart;
        $end = $ipEnd;
    }
    $result = array();
    while($end >= $start){
        $maxSize = 32;
        while ($maxSize > 0){
            $mask = hexdec(iMask($maxSize - 1));
            $maskBase = $start & $mask;
            if($maskBase != $start) break;
            $maxSize--;
        }
        $x = log($end - $start + 1)/log(2);
        $maxDiff = floor(32 - floor($x));

        if($maxSize < $maxDiff){
            $maxSize = $maxDiff;
        }

        $ip = long2ip($start);
        array_push($result, "$ip/$maxSize");
        $start += pow(2, (32-$maxSize));
    }
    return $result;
}
function iMask($s){
    return base_convert((pow(2, 32) - pow(2, (32-$s))), 10, 16);
}
```

(note: corrected 'echo' to 'return' result)

I've tried all of the suggested ways of "feeding" the $ipStart and $ipEnd values to the function, and also to "echo" or "print" the resulting array, but all I get is the word "Array".

For example, after the function is defined, I try:

```
$ipStart = '8.8.8.8';
$ipEnd = '8.8.8.254';
echo iprange2cidr($ipStart, $ipEnd);
```

... I appologise for the novice question, I'm a PHP newbie. I'm just not sure how to use the function. Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated! My server uses PHP 7.1. Thank you.

Comment: `echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: instead of `echo $result` do a `return $result;`. and remember that result is an array so you have to convert it to a string before printing.

Comment: What are you expecting to be the result of the function - what is the CIDR you expect?

Comment: If you have a range of 8.8.8.1 to 8.8.8.10, the CIDR output should be: 8.8.8.1/32
8.8.8.2/31
8.8.8.4/30
8.8.8.8/31
8.8.8.10/32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's return `$result` instead.

```
function iprange2cidr($ipStart, $ipEnd){
    ....
    return $result;
}
```

Then let's convert it to a string before we echo it:

```
$ipStart = '8.8.8.8';
$ipEnd = '8.8.8.254';
$range = iprange2cidr($ipStart, $ipEnd);
echo implode("\n",$range);
```

Comment: I tried explode, it gave an error that 2nd paramater must be a string not an array. Then I tried "implode" and it worked:  echo implode ("<br>",$range);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print_r($result);` to get human-readable output.

see [doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

proper way of using function is to return value like

```
    function iprange2cidr($ipStart, $ipEnd){
....
return $result;}
```

and then call the function like 
$returnedVale = iprange2cidr($ipStart, $ipEnd);

```
$returnedVale = iprange2cidr($ipStart, $ipEnd);
echo"<pre>";print_r($returnedVale);echo"</pre>";
```